# Meaning of "intellectual farce"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

> Overview
>
> Aristophanes was the greatest writer of Old Comedy in
>   Athens in the fifth century BCE and the only playwright
>   from that era with any complete plays surviving. Old
>   Comedy was a form of drama that has no parallel in
>   subsequent European literature. It was a mixture of fantasy,
>   political and personal satire, farce, obscenity, and, in
>   the case of Aristophanes at least, delightful lyric poetry.
>   Although he used the language brilliantly, Aristophanes
>   was above all an inspired creator of bizarre fantasy worlds
>   that defy fundamental laws of rationality and logic. He
>   paid little attention to consistency of time, place, or
>   character and was not very interested in the logical development
>   of a dramatic plot. He brought to his art a
>   command of every kind of comedy, from slapstick to
>   **intellectual farce**. Parody was one of his specialities, and
>   he had a devastating way of deflating pomposity in politics,
>   social life, and literature.

I don't get its meaning clearly and I searched on the net but I didn't find an acceptable answer.

Dose it mean: it this kind of comedy he made fun of intellectual way to solve problems?

Sorce: Gale Contextual Encyclopedia Of World Literature

Answer (score 3):

"farce" on its own, (in this context) means a humourous play (or film, or possibly a book)

But the rest of the sentence is also talking about kinds of comedy, where "slapstick" is at one end, (and by inference 'low brow', 'simple' etc.) so in this case "farce" has been qualified, upgraded even, by attaching the word "intellectual" to refer to comedy that requires a certain degree of intelligence to understand, and arguably required more intelligence to write.